# How to include a module in a factory_girl factory?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, module, mixins, factory-bot

I'm trying to reuse a helper method in all my factories, however I cannot get it to work. Here's my setup:

### Helper module (in spec/support/test_helpers.rb)

```
module Tests
  module Helpers
    # not guaranteed to be unique, useful for generating passwords
    def random_string(length = 20)
      chars = ['A'..'Z', 'a'..'z', '0'..'9'].map{|r|r.to_a}.flatten
      (0...length).map{ chars[rand(chars.size)] }.join
    end
  end
end
```

### A factory (in spec/factories/users.rb)

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user do
    sequence(:username) { |n| "username-#{n}" }
    password random_string
    password_confirmation { |u| u.password }
  end
end
```

If I run my tests (with `rake spec`), I get the following error wherever I create a user with `Factory(:user)`:

```
 Failure/Error: Factory(:user)
 ArgumentError:
   Not registered: random_string
```

**What do I have to do to be able to use `random_string` in my factories?**

I have tried the following:

- using `include Tests::Helpers` at every level of my factory (before the `define`, between `define` and `factory :user` and inside `factory :user`)
- in `spec_helper.rb`, I have the following already: `config.include Tests::Helpers` and it gives me access to `random_string` in my specs
- simply requiring the file in my factory

I have also read the following links without success:

- [Define helper methods in a module](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/docs/helper-methods/define-helper-methods-in-a-module)
- [Different ways of code reuse in RSpec](http://testdrivenwebsites.com/2011/08/17/different-ways-of-code-reuse-in-rspec/)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

What about a mere:

```
module Tests
  module Helpers
    # not guaranteed to be unique, useful for generating passwords
    def self.random_string(length = 20)
      chars = ['A'..'Z', 'a'..'z', '0'..'9'].map{|r|r.to_a}.flatten
      (0...length).map{ chars[rand(chars.size)] }.join
    end
  end
end
```

Then:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user do
    sequence(:username) { |n| "username-#{n}" }
    password Tests::Helpers.random_string
    password_confirmation { |u| u.password }
  end
end
```

---

Ok, got it :) Do as follows:

```
module FactoryGirl
  class DefinitionProxy
    def random_string
     #your code here
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: It works like that but I was hoping I would not have to write the whole namespace. I'll keep the question open in case someone finds a better way.

Comment: It works, though I ended leaving my helper module as it is (with an instance method though) and including that module inside the `DefinitionProxy` class. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Important to note: my `rand` method did not work as is and I had to replace it with `Kernel.rand` due to some conflict with FactoryGirl.

Answer (score 7):

apneadiving's answer did not work for me. I had to do the following:

```
# /spec/support/factory_helpers.rb
module FactoryHelpers
  def my_helper_method
    # ...
  end
end

FactoryGirl::Proxy.send(:include, FactoryHelpers)
```

Then you can use it as follows:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :post do
    title { my_helper_method }
  end
end
```

Comment: Looks much simpler, I'll try it when I have time.

Comment: FG v4 doesn't use ::Proxy anymore - fwiw, you get the same effect by replacing `FactoryGirl::Proxy.send` in @cuvius answer with `FactoryGirl::SyntaxRunner.send` But note that the gem's developer is [thinking on a proper solution within the gem itself](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/issues/564), so keep track of those developments as well if you're doing this.

Answer (score 4):

I tested other answers yesterday (24.04.2012) and... none of them actually works.

Looks like Factory Girl gem (v3.2.0) have changed a lot.

But I figured out a quick solution:

```
# factories.rb
module FactoryMacros
  def self.create_file(path)
    file = File.new(path)
    file.rewind
    return ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile.new(:tempfile => file,
                                            :filename => File.basename(file))
  end
end
# also factories.rb
FactoryGirl.define do

  factory :thing do |t|
    t.file { FactoryMacros::create_file("path-to-file")
  end
end
```