# FactoryGirl clean up code

Tags: ruby-on-rails, factory-bot, faker

Here's my Ride factory:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :ride do
    departure_address "#{Faker::Address.street_address}, #{Faker::Address.city} #{Faker::Address.country}"
  end
end
```

How to clean up this ugly code? `"#{Faker::Address.street_address}, #{Faker::Address.city} #{Faker::Address.country}"`

I'd like to create a `fake_full_address` method inside test/helpers and call it from the factory. How to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Under **/lib** you can put your helper module:

```
module MyHelper
  def self.full_address
    "#{Faker::Address.street_address}, #{Faker::Address.city} #{Faker::Address.country}"
  end
end
```

The in your factory you can us it including your helper:

```
require 'my_helper.rb'

FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :ride do
    departure_address MyHelper.full_address
  end
end
```

I did this on my project and it works well, but you can check these options too...

[How to include a module in a factory_girl factory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7907737/how-to-include-a-module-in-a-factory-girl-factory)

https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/issues/564